# Additional django-registration fields

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I have followed various tutorials and solutions on how to add additional fields to `django-registration` module. Some of them did the trick, but after I synced the database, data is not saved. Here are my files:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Organization(models.Model):
    #user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, unique=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from django import forms
from drugisok.models import Organization

class OrganizationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Organization


RegistrationForm.base_fields.update(OrganizationForm.base_fields)

class CustomRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    def save(self, profile_callback=None):
        user = super(CustomRegistrationForm, self).save(profile_callback=None)
        org, c = Organization.objects.get_or_create(user=user, name=self.cleaned_data['name'])
```

There is a table in the database with name `drugisok_organization` which corresponds to the model created. In that table there is a column named `name` which also corresponds to the model. HTML form itself shows one additional text input for `name`, but name is not saved when the form is submitted.

Comment: what do you mean by data is not saved? Are those fields created in the database?

Comment: Yes, the fields are created. However, I've found out that it's better to use dmitko's approach explained [here](http://dmitko.ru/django-registration-form-custom-field/).

Sadly, it also gives me strange errors, so my next question is about that.